# replace a line that contains a string with special characters

Tags: sed

i want to replace lines which contains a string that has some special characters.
i used \ and \ for escape special characters but nothing changes in file.
i use sed like this:

```
> sed -i '/pnconfig\[\'dbhost\'\] = \'localhost\'/c\This line is removed.' tco.php
```

i just want to find lines that contains :

```
$pnconfig['dbhost'] = 'localhost';
```

and replace that line with:

```
  $pnconfig['dbhost'] = '1.1.1.1';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the sed in double quotes as

```
sed -i "s/\(pnconfig\['dbhost'\] = \)'localhost'/\1'1.1.1.1'/" filename
```

**Test**

```
$ echo "\$pnconfig['dbhost'] = 'localhost';" | sed "s/\(pnconfig\['dbhost'\] = \)'localhost'/\1'1.1.1.1'/"
$pnconfig['dbhost'] = '1.1.1.1';
```

Comment: but why should use /\1'1.1.1.1'/ instead of /'1.1.1.1'/ ?

Comment: @Mickey Because `\1` is the first capture group which contians `pnconfig\['dbhost'\] = `. I was little lazy to type them all over again in the replacemnet part :P

Comment: i used sed -i "s/\(pnconfig\['dbhost'\] = \)'localhost'/pnconfig\['dbhost'\] = \'1.1.1.1'/" myfile  and the result was the same.  but why should use () or why not use ) after 'localhost' like this:        sed -i "s/\(pnconfig\['dbhost'\] = 'localhost'\)/pnconfig\['dbhost'\] = \'1.1.1.1'/" myfile

Answer (score 0):

Use as below:

```
sed -i.bak '/pnconfig\[\'dbhost\'\] = \'localhost\'/pnconfig\[\'dbhost\'\] = \'1.1.1.1\'/' tco.php
```

Rather than modifying the file for the first time, create back up and then search for your pattern and then replace it with the other as above in your file tco.php

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry about backslashing single quotes by using double quotes for sed.

```
sed -i.bak "/pnconfig\['dbhost'\] = 'localhost'/s/localhost/1.1.1.1/g" File
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
sed "/$pnconfig\['dbhost']/s/localhost/1.1.1.1/"
```